# Generalization of image patches using mean shift?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm reading this paper - https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.04112.pdf and trying to understand the answer to the author's first question -

> *why a nonlinear activation
>   function is essential at the filter output of all intermediate layers?*

His explanation seemed comprehensible up till this point -

*We can further generalize the RECOS model to a translated unit sphere*

[image: Eq. (5) in paper]

where μ is the mean of x.

I was confused why this was considered a "generalization", but the paper proceeds to explain why this was done.

> For vision problems, elements x<sub>n</sub> , n = 1...N , of **x** denote N pixel
>   values of an input image, and μ is the mean of all pixels. If the input
>   is a full image, its mean is the global mean that has no impact on image
>   understanding.
>
> It can be removed before the processing. Thus, we set μ=0.
>
> However, if an input image is large, we often partition it into smaller patches,and process all patches in parallel. In this case, the mean of each patch is a local mean. It should not be removed since an integration of local means provides a coarse view of the full image. This corresponds to the general case in Eq. (5).

I completely understand trying to represent small patches using their mean.

**Is mean shifting the signal/vector considered a generalization?** 
If so, can someone please point me to theory that substantiates that claim? I can't seem to find a suitable link myself.

Or is it just used here to illustrate the author's example and later explanations?

Or am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you heard about standardization of the probability distribution (or features in general)? You shift its mean so that it resembles a Gaussian (normal) distribution. Take a look at the [Central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) as well as a paper [A review of mean-shift algorithms for clustering](http://faculty.ucmerced.edu/mcarreira-perpinan/papers/mean-shift-review.pdf)